# Is it possible to use C++ template to control code generation?

Tags: c++, templates, macros, code-generation

it is possible to use C++ templates to controle code generation?

Something like (pseudocode...)

```
template<int i, int j> void f() {
#if i > j
#define
  //code...
#else
  //code...
#endif
}
```

(i'm starting to get used with the templates, but i would like to know how much powerful they are).

Thank you!

Comment: Yup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Metaprogramming like this is usually done with a combination of specialization and overloading. In your case, tag dispatch (turning values into types) is a viable solution:

```
#include <type_traits>

void f_impl(std::true_type) { /* ... */ }
void f_impl(std::false_type) { /* ... */ }

template <int i, int j> void f() {
  f_impl(std::integral_constant<bool, (i > j)>());
}
```